How to prove the inequality for the standard deviation of a linear combination of two random variables
The question comes from ‘Mathematics for Finance: An Introduction to Financial Engineering’ by Marek Capiński (Author), Tomasz Zastawniak. The book provides a conclusion about the risk and return of two assets, each given according to$\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}<\rho_{12}<1$
;$-1<\rho_{12}<\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}$;
$\rho_{12}=1$However, it does not provide a detailed proof. The lack of detailed mathematical proof has left me confused. I have not found any related answers online, so I am raising the question here.I believe this can help others who are also concerned about mathematical proofs.
The variance of the linear combination V of random variables X₁ and X₂ is given by the following formula: $\sigma_{V}^{2} = s^{2} \sigma_{1}^{2}+(1-s)^2 \sigma_{2}^{2}+2 s(1-s) c_{12}$,
where s and (1-s) are the coefficients of the linear combination, $c_{12}$ represents the covariance of two random variables.
When the variance of the combination V with respect to s has a derivative of zero, the expression for s can be written as:
$s_{0} = \frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}-c_{12}}{\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}-2 c_{12}}$ if $\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}<\rho_{12}<1$.
Then $s_{0}>1, \rho_{12}$ is the linear correlation coefficient between random variable 1 and random variable 2.
Given
$\sigma_1 <\sigma_2, \sigma_{V}^{2} = s_{0}^{2} \sigma_{1}^{2}+(1-s_{0})^2 \sigma_{2}^{2}+2 s_{0}(1-s_{0}) c_{12},$ prove $\sigma_v <\sigma_1.$
geogebra diagram

There was a person who provided an answer. Although I didn’t fully understand his answer, his response was very enlightening to me. Therefore, I found a way to prove this problem. Even though he has already deleted his answer, I would like to express my gratitude here!
First, transform $σ_{v}^2$ into the form of a standard quadratic function.
\begin{aligned}
&\sigma _{v}^{2}=s^{2}\sigma _{1}^{2}+\left( 1-s\right) ^{2}\sigma _{2}^{2}+2s\left( 1-s\right) c_{12}\\
&=s^{2}\sigma _{1}^{2}+\left( 1-2s+s^{2}\right) \sigma _{2}^{2}+2s\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}-2s^{2}\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\\
&=s^{2}\left( \sigma _{1}^{2}+\sigma _{2}^{2}-2\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\right) +s\left( 2\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}-2\sigma _{2}^{2}\right) +\sigma _{2}^{2}
\end{aligned}
Consider ‘s’ as the independent variable and the rest as coefficients.
\begin{aligned}
&y=ax^{2}+bx+c\\
& \because a >0\\
& \therefore y\geq \dfrac{4ac-b^{2}}{4a}\\
& so\ \ \ \sigma _{v}^{2}\geq \dfrac{4\left( \sigma _{1}^{2}+\sigma _{2}^{2}-2\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\right) \sigma _{2}^{2}-\left( 2\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}-2\sigma _{2}^{2}\right) ^{2}}{4\left( \sigma _{1}^{2}+\sigma _{2}^{2}-2\rho \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\right) }
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
& \sigma_v^2 \geqslant \frac{\left(1-\rho^2\right) \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \\
& \because \rho<1 \\
& \therefore \sigma_v^2 \leqslant \frac{\left(\rho^2-1\right) \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \\
& \because \sigma_v>0 \\
& \therefore \sigma_v \leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\rho^2\right)} \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2 \rho \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2}} \\
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
& \because \rho<1 \\
& 2 \rho\sigma_1 \sigma_2<2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
& \\
& \therefore \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2}} < \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_1 \sigma_2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2} \\
& \because 1-\rho^2<1 \\
& \therefore \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_2<\sigma_2<\sigma_1+\sigma_2 \\
& \therefore \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_2}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}<1 \\
& \therefore \frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_2 \sigma_1}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}<\sigma_1 \\
&So \ \ \sigma _{v}<\sigma _{1}
\end{aligned}
